# Service Broker Or SqlDependency in SqlLocalDb?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, localdb

Is `SqlDependency` supported in `SqlLocalDb`? If yes how to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question about Service Broker in your subject.

Service Broker should work fine in LocalDB, but only local queues are available. Remote queues won't work, in either direction (in fact Service Broker queues are bi-directional, so there's no incoming/outgoing queue distinction).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly but may be below link can be useful for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934450.aspx